# grep exclude on sentence with [ character

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I need to do a grep which excludes sentences which contain 'This is a sentence [WARN]' for example:

> aaaabbbbccccThis is a sentence [WARN]ccccdddd

but when I do:

> grep WARN log/* | grep -v -E 'This is a sentence [WARN]'

it doesnt work. I think this is because of the "[" and "]" because if I do:

> grep WARN log/* | grep -v -E 'This is a sentence'

it works. How can I exclude a sentence containing square brackets?

**EDIT:**

Sorry I should have said- the string is actually a substring. So I may have:

> aaaabbbbccccThis is a sentence [WARN]ccccdddd

which needs to be excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-E` is for extended regexp. Just escape the `[]` brackets, and you should be good.

```
grep WARN log/* | grep -v -E 'This is a sentence \[WARN\]'
```

`[]` brackets means character class when not escaped, so what your pattern would actually look for was one of the following substrings:

- This is a sentence W
- This is a sentence A
- This is a sentence R
- This is a sentence N

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell grep to use the string as fixed string. For this, you can use `-F`:

```
grep WARN log/* | grep -v -F 'This is a sentence [WARN]'
```

From `man grep`:

> -F, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines,
>   any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

#### Test

```
$ cat a
This is a sentence [LOG]
This is a sentence [WARN]
$ grep -v "sentence [LOG]" a   <---- [LOG] is taken as regex
This is a sentence [LOG]
This is a sentence [WARN]
$ grep -Fv "sentence [LOG]" a   <---- [LOG] is taken literally
This is a sentence [WARN]
```

Or with updated input:

```
$ cat a
aaaabbbbccccThis is a sentence [WARN]ccccdddd
aaaabbbbccccThis is a sentence [LOG]ccccdddd
hello!
$ grep -vF "sentence [WARN]" a
aaaabbbbccccThis is a sentence [LOG]ccccdddd
hello!
```

Comment: Sorry I should have said- the string is actually a substring. So I may have aaaabbbbccccThis is a sentence [WARN]ccccdddd which needs to be excluded.

Comment: Can you post a full example input and desired output to have it 100% clear? We must be very close to the solution.

Comment: have edited my question. I simply want an exclusion on a contains, for part of a sentence.